# Reading Fortran PARAMETER from an input file

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I have a fluid flow solver in Fortran 90 and I am presenting only the relevant portion here. I can read variables from an input file but is there a way to read variables which are declared as `PARAMETER`?

For example,
`NX`, `NY`, and `NZ` variables are parameters and declared as

`INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DP=SELECTED_REAL_KIND(14),NX=256, NY=209, NZ=64`

because they are used to allocated arrays later, e.g.,

`REAL(KIND=DP), Dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: Exp_TH`

`allocate(Exp_TH(1:NX,1:NZ,1:NY))`

My question is: is there a way to read in `NX`, `NY`, and `NZ` variables from an input file as they are declared the type `PARAMETER`?